# List/Array Diffing Algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, list, algorithm

I'd like to implement List/Array diffing in C#, but I've hit a snag. Here's what I have so far:

```
public struct ListDiff
{
    public IReadOnlyList<int> Insertions { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<int> Deletions { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<(int source, int destination)> Moves { get; }

    ListDiff(IReadOnlyList<int> insertions, IReadOnlyList<int> deletions, IReadOnlyList<(int, int)> moves)
    {
        Insertions = insertions;
        Deletions = deletions;
        Moves = moves;
    }

    static IReadOnlyDictionary<T, int> ToDict<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> values)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<T, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); ++i)
        {
            dict[values[i]] = i;
        }

        return dict;
    }

    // Assuming a T with a meaningful implementation of GetHashCode()
    public static ListDiff GetDiff<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> previous, IReadOnlyList<T> current)
    {
        // map into Dictionary<T, int> for fast "contains member"-lookup
        var previousDict = ToDict(previous);
        var currentDict = ToDict(current);

        var deletions = new List<int>();
        var insertions = new List<int>();
        var moves = new List<(int source, int destination)>();

        foreach (var (item, index) in previousDict)
        {
            if (currentDict.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                if (currentDict[item] != index)
                {
                    // item is in both and its index has changed == it moved
                    moves.Add((index, currentDict[item]));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // item was in previous, not in current
                deletions.Add(index);
            }
        }

        foreach (var (item, index) in currentDict)
        {
            if (!previousDict.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                // item is in current, not in previous
                insertions.Add(index);
            }
        }

        return new ListDiff(insertions, deletions, moves);
    }
}
```

There are three types of "actions": `insertions`, `deletions`, and `moves`. This all works fine--if not super efficiently--for identifying items that were inserted and deleted. The snag is that any items that were "moved" as a result of insertions or deletions are returned as `moves`: i.e. if `myItem` was in the old List at index 1 and the new List deleted at 0, `myItem` counts as a move from 1->0 even though its movement was strictly a result of other actions.

**For my purposes I need to ignore moves that were strictly a result of other actions. What algorithm can I use to "cancel out" redundant moves?**

Or is there a library/built-in method I'm missing that does this more efficiently than I could ever dream?

General Notes:

- I'm currently dealing with Lists of at most 3 items, but would like to apply this process to Lists of potentially around 100 elements
- awaiting an async semi-long-running process is acceptable if necessary
- A solution that also accounts for "updated" Ts is ideal but not necessary

Comment: Perhaps you should first detect items that were deleted, then you can make adjustments for false "moves".

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://github.com/kinetiq/Ether.ListCompare ... It works, I'm using it in production in several projects, however I haven't written the docs for it yet. This is a good reminder. If you want to use it I can throw some directions up there.

Comment: ...It currently supports ID-based comparisons and some more advanced equality-based cases, where you implement IEqualityComparer. Does not use async, but I'm not sure that would help here.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up working out a different solution, but thanks for the pointers!